# How to resolve " httpResponseCode 401 httpResponseMessage os_authType was 'any' and an invalid cookie was sent."

Tags: networking, bamboo, jira-agile

I have installed Bamboo server in my environment and monitor the application through New Relic.
After upgrading of the server, the server is now giving these errors :

```
         httpResponseCode   401
         httpResponseMessage    os_authType was 'any' and an invalid cookie was sent.
```

Googled about the solution, found out that these errors occur when multiple users are logged-in to the portal. So, removed all the users who were logged-in, but the result was same. So any help regarding this will be appreciated.

Comment: Elapsed cookies can cause some servers to return a 401 error code. Maybe the server upgrade has caused all cookies to be invalidated. Try to renew your login or cookies. You might need first to delete all existing  cookies from the browser.

Comment: You didn't cite any of your sources for your research

Answer (score 0):

Elapsed cookies can cause some servers to return a 401 error code.

It is possible that the server upgrade has caused all existing cookies to be
invalidated.

Try to renew your login or cookies. You might need first to delete in
the browser all existing cookies of your website.

Answer (score 0):

The *os_authType* with '*any*' happens only if a username and password are not specified and there is no valid cookie, the server will return a 401 error response.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).